# Change column color of a list webpart

Tags: javascript, css, column

We have a landing page that consist of a scheduled maintenance list webpart and we want to have a color coded background for a column. For example:
In Progress = Red
Completed = Green

[image]

I tried the JSON column formatting but it only works on a list not a webpart. Also the input on the list webpart may change everyday so i can't apply static CSS.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you able to deploy custom web parts?

Comment: When i check the add webpart ribbon it has a Custom category which consist of Autocomplete textbox, book review, docdownload count, sharepoint.intranet.finder and a lot more. Is this it?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't sound like you created these. I'm asking if you can deploy solutions to the farm. Otherwise, you need to write some JavaScript as Kasper mentions below.

Comment: I don't have access to that. :(

Comment: You don't have SharePoint Designer either?

Answer (score 1):

Try some jQuery like this. This will look at each row and change the background color. Let me know if you need help implementing this.

```
$(function(){
            $("td.ms-vb2").each(function(){
                var that = $(this);

                      if (that.text() == "Completed"){
                            that.parent("tr").children("td").css("background-color", "#0000FF");
                }else if (that.text() == "in Progress"){
                            that.parent("tr").children("td").css("background-color", "#008000");
                }else if (that.text() == "Ongoing"){
                            that.parent("tr").children("td").css("background-color", "#FF0000");
                }

            });
        });
```

Comment: I tried to put this on a script editor and all the column was replaced by this error "TypeError: Unable to get property 'style' of undefined or null reference" also some errors were "TypeError: Unable to get property '_events' of undefined or null reference"

Comment: so instead of text, you're seeing the error messages you just listed?

Comment: Yeah. All the column disappeared.

Comment: You may need to add a reference to jQuery if you haven't done so already.
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. The error disappears and it is back to normal but there is no changes on the columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the JS Link functionality of list view and can achieve this result easily.

Here is some code that you need to put in a JS file, Lets say in `TaskListJSLink.js`.

```
(function () {
    var statusFieldCtx = {};
    statusFieldCtx.Templates = {};
    statusFieldCtx.Templates.Fields = {
        "Status": {  //The internal name of that column.
            "View": StatusFieldViewTemplate
        }
    };

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(statusFieldCtx);

    function StatusFieldViewTemplate(ctx) { //Function to change the status styling
        var statusValue = ctx.CurrentItem[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.Name]; //To get the current item's status value.
        if (statusValue == "Completed") {
            return "<div style='background-color:green;color:white'>" + statusValue + "</div>";
        }
        if (statusValue == "In Progress") {
          return "<div style='background-color:red;color:white'>" + statusValue + "</div>";
        }
        else{
            return statusValue;
        }
    }
})();
```

Next step is to add the file reference into list view. Suppose your JS file is currently in `/SiteAssets/TaskListJSLink.js`

So, edit the page and edit the list web part. 
In the miscellaneous section, add the link reference in JS Link setting as - `~sitecollection/SiteAssets/TaskListJSLink.js`.

The `~sitecollection` is required in the beginning to provide correct path otherwise it won't work.

Now, Save the changes and see the magic.

[image]

Well, you can achieve more with this JSLink functionality like -

[image]

Ping me if you want to know.

Comment: Using Client-side Rendering and JSLink, as described here, is the right solution for this problem on SP 2013 or later.

Answer (score 0):

How about a JavaScript that checks the text in the status column and changes the css background color accordingly?

Comment: That's what i'm thinking about but i'm not that proficient on javascript. What I'm having problem about is that the items being inputted changes everyday so the ID or Class of the Column also changes.

Comment: That shouldn't matter. You can have the JS (jQuery) look just at the text in that column and change the background color.

Answer (score 0):

try using jslink to render the page / view.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/2447b5c7-e8bb-4c08-84d0-9f4b791159a7/sharepoint-2013-using-jslinks-to-color-code-a-column?forum=sharepointdevelopment

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in the script editor webpart,

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("table.ms-listviewtable tr td").each(function(){
    if($(this).text()=="In Progress")
    {
        $(this).css("background-color","#ff3333");
    }
    else if($(this).text()=="Completed")
    {
        $(this).css("background-color","#00ff55");
    }
    else if($(this).text()=="Ongoing")
    {
        $(this).css("background-color","#c2d6d6");
    }
 });
});

</script>
```

Its similar to [jpollar](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/243635/58747) answer.