# JSLink not modifying text

Tags: 2013, javascript, list-form, jslink, conditional

I am trying to get a super simple JS script to work on my SharePoint. I found this example [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/243628/change-column-color-of-a-list-webpart). This is what I am working with:

```
(function () {
var statusFieldCtx = {};
statusFieldCtx.Templates = {};
statusFieldCtx.Templates.Fields = {
    "Location": {  //The internal name of that column.
        "View": StatusFieldViewTemplate
    }
};

SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(statusFieldCtx);

function StatusFieldViewTemplate(ctx) { //Function to change the status styling
    var statusValue = ctx.CurrentItem[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.Name]; //To get the current item's status value.
    if (statusValue == "Equipment Room") {
        return "<div style='background-color:green;color:white'>" + statusValue + "</div>";
    }
    if (statusValue == "Treatment Room") {
      return "<div style='background-color:red;color:white'>" + statusValue + "</div>";
    }
    else{
        return statusValue;
    }
}
})();
```

This script does nothing at all. I did put in a `alert("Override call worked");` to ensure that it is linked appropriately.

Am I missing something? This is working with SharePoint 2013.

Comment: You put the `alert` in the `StatusFieldViewTemplate` function?  Did you put a breakpoint after you assign `statusValue` so you can inspect it's value (and also maybe inspect the `ctx` object to see if you can see anything in there?  What type of field is the `Location` field?

Comment: The `Location` field is a `Single line of text` type. Hmm, nope, the `Alert` only worked in the main function, not the `StatusFieldViewTemplate` function. . . How can I set a breakpoint? Sorry, this is rather new to me.

Comment: Hmm, then somehow the override is not getting registered.  Are you sure that `Location` is truly the internal name of the field?  Easiest way to check that is to go to the List Settings page for the list, scroll down to the Columns section and click the column name.  On the "Edit Column" page, look at the URL for a query parameter "Field=" and there will be the internal name of the field.  To set a breakpoint. open the browser dev tools (I think  F12 on most).  in Chrome there is a tab called "Sources" and in FF and IE I think it's called "Debugger" where you can find a list of the script...

Comment: ... files being loaded.  Find yours and it will show you the code, and you can set a breakpoint there, then refresh the page and it should stop when it hits the breakpoint.

Comment: Well, turns out `Location` is actually `x5vw`. Thanks for that! Still cannot get the `StatusFieldViewTemplate` function to work. I will try the debugger and see what I can find.

Comment: You solved my question! Can you please make your comment to an answer? It was the 'Field' name (I also had some cache issues, but some 'Shift + F5' fixed that up).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would double check that "Location" is truly the *internal* name of the field.  Sometimes the display name can change, and to register the CSR override you need to use the internal name.

The easiest way to check that is to go to the List Settings page for the list, scroll down to the Columns section and click on the name of the column.  on the Edit Column page, look at the URL for a query param "Field=", and there you will see the actual internal name of the field.